# is there a way to solve the problem No module named 'werkzeug.posixemulation' on odoo14

Tags: python, odoo

I have configured pycharm to develop odoo modules and launch the odoo server. it worked without problem and one day I launched a python flask project under the same interpreter and since then I can't launch my odoo server, when I try I get this error "No module named 'werkzeug.posixemulation'". I'm a beginner and how can I solve my problem. thank you. I'll throw in an image if needed. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbzii.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've got it, I just need to uninstall werkzeug 2.0.1 and install werkzeug 1.0.1 with the command pip install werkzeug==1.0.1

Answer (score 0):

The werkzeug version listed in the [requirements.txt](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/42d1c3cf78b1ba7baf39e3bf9e0ba09abbb63568/requirements.txt#L50) file is`0.16.1`:

```
Werkzeug==0.16.1
```

It is preferable to use the same version